# a function to create and add to an object

Tags: javascript

Complete a function that takes in three parameters, an object, and a string (which will represent a key), and a value. The function needs to add a property to the inputted object. The property's key is a string, and the value of this property should be the inputted value. The function should return the inputted object.

```
function addProperty(obj, key, value) {
  // your code here
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}
```

As this function stands it takes in one key and one value. I need it to let me add as many keys and values as I want. Please help.

Comment: You have 2 options either take an array as a parameter and loop through it to add properties into an array or you can loop over the array of the property and then call the function as many times as the length of the array.

Comment: Third option: You could make the function accept any number of additional parameters, so that it can be called using `addProperty(obj, key, value, key2, value2, …)` then. The old-school way to read an arbitrary number of parameters would be [the arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments); or in ES6 via [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: Remove the `var obj = {};` line

Comment: Your code is almost correct. It must not declare a local variable `obj`. `obj` is received as argument, all that the code should do is to set its property `key` with the value `value` (exactly what the second line of the function does) then return the input object (what the third line of the code already does). That's all. By calling the function (after you fix it) repeatedly you can set any number of properties of the object you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Passing array of `key` and `value`

```js
function addProperty(obj, keyArr, valueArr) {
  keyArr.forEach((k, i) => {
    obj[k] = valueArr[i];
  });
  return obj;
}

const keys = ["A", "B", "C"];
const values = ["value of A", "value of A", "value of A"];
let obj = {};

obj = addProperty(obj, keys, values);
console.log(obj);
```

**2)** Iterating over array `key` and calling the function as many times as length of the `key` array

```js
function addProperty(obj, key, value) {
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}

const keys = ["A", "B", "C"];
const values = ["value of A", "value of A", "value of A"];
let obj = {};

keys.forEach((k, i) => {
  obj = addProperty(obj, k, values[i]);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help everyone, I'm going to try these now and see which works best.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
function addProperty(obj, keys_and_values) {
  // your code here
  var obj = {}
  for (let key in keys_and_values) {
      obj[key] = keys_and_values[key]
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(addProperty({}, {"name": "hi", "age": 69}))
```

**output**

```
{
  age: 69,
  name: "hi"
}
```

Comment: why to use for..in loop when you can do `obj = { ...keys_and_values }`

Comment: With `{ ...keys_and_values }` you'll get a copy of obj and not an object which uses the values as keys. -> `{"name": "hi", "age": 69}`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove `var obj = {}` in your addProperty function. I think you want to pass the object which should be expanded, right?

```js
var obj = {};
var data = [{
    key: "KEYA",
    value: "VALUEA"
  },
  {
    key: "KEYB",
    value: "VALUEB"
  }
];

var data2 = [{
    key: "KEYC",
    value: "VALUEC"
  }
];


//Add key/value pairs to obj
console.log(addProperty(obj, data));

//Add another key/value pair to obj
console.log(addProperty(obj, data2));

function addProperty(obj, data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    obj[data[key].key] = data[key].value;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why everyone were over explaining the question here-
We need to achieve 3 things here-
Function needs to add a property to the inputted object.
The value of property should be the inputted value.
function should return the inputted object.

**function** addProperty(obj, key, value) {

obj[key] = value ;

return obj ;

}

Comment: No.. Please read the question. " need it to let me add as many keys and values as I want"